# Wordpress Slider doesn't loop properly

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, slider, carousel

So this is a plugin - I'm not sure how effective it is to ask this here but no one is responding on the wordpress forums. Here's hoping! :)

If you follow [this link](http://test.allcityinsurance.ca/about-us/), and scroll down near the bottom of the page, there's a section that says "Meet the Team." This section is on a carousel that uses something called "Post Carousel" as part of a plugin called "Visual Composer." Once it gets to the end of the posts, it leaves blank spaces until it loops around to the beginning. I'd like to remove these blanks spaces so that the carousel is seamless.

Thoughts?

Comment: Ideally it should loop instead of sliding back to the beginning, but I'm not familiar enough with the code to determine how to do this. Learning!

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/carousel-horizontal-posts-content-slider/screenshots/  Is it this one?

Comment: I believe it's http://codecanyon.net/item/carousel-anything-for-visual-composer/8621711 - but it's built into visual composer for themeforest. Maybe.